# Google showing wrong country

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, geolocation

I'm in the UK but whenever I go on to `www.google.com` in incognito, it always goes to the UAE version and I don't know how to fix it. It shows UK when I'm signed in.

At the bottom of the page it says "From your IP address" but every other website such as `https://www.whatismyip.com/` says it's in the UK. I tried the `Update location` button but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? It's the same for multiple devices on my home network. (I'm not using a VPN)

Devices:

- Windows 10, Chrome 96.0.4664.45
- Android 11, Chrome 96.0.4664.45

Comment: Please checkout the duplicate target. If you still need help please update this question, including a brief explanation about why the answers to the linked duplicate target were not helpful or why they don't meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

most of the time it changes (your location) after doing some searches.
so what I mean is it could be because of your searches.